# symbolic quantum computing using sympy : how to use arbitrary gate?

Tags: programming

I'm trying to use sympy to compute symbolic results of quantum circuits using dirac notation. 
More specifically, I'd like to use the three rotation gates. I try to implement them in the following way, using sympy symbolic quantum physics package :

```
from IPython.display import display

from sympy import init_printing
init_printing(use_latex=True)
from sympy import expand, Eq, Symbol, simplify, exp, sin,cos,I,srepr,Matrix
from sympy.physics.quantum import *
from sympy.physics.quantum.qubit import *
from sympy.physics.quantum.gate import *
from sympy.physics.quantum.circuitplot import circuit_plot


theta = Symbol('theta')

Ry_mat = Matrix([[cos(theta/2), -sin(theta/2)],[sin(theta/2),cos(theta/2)]]) #check
Rx_mat = Matrix([[cos(theta/2), -I*sin(theta/2)],[-I*sin(theta/2),cos(theta/2)]]) #check

Ry = UGate((0,), Ry_mat)
Rx= UGate((1,), Rx_mat)
c = Ry*Rx
circuit_plot(c, nqubits=2);

qapply(c*Qubit('00'))
```

I get the error **unhashable type: 'MutableDenseMatrix'**
when executing qapply. I tried to replace the line :

```
c = Rx*Ry
```

with

```
c = Rx
```

and then there is no more errors. Does someone know what's going on ? What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why this doesn't work with `Matrix`, but a fix for this would be to use `ImmutableMatrix` instead

```
from sympy import Symbol, sin, cos, I, ImmutableMatrix
from sympy.physics.quantum import qapply
from sympy.physics.quantum.qubit import Qubit
from sympy.physics.quantum.gate import UGate

theta = Symbol('theta')

Ry_mat = ImmutableMatrix([[cos(theta/2), -sin(theta/2)],
                        [sin(theta/2),cos(theta/2)]])
Rx_mat = ImmutableMatrix([[cos(theta/2), -I*sin(theta/2)],
                        [-I*sin(theta/2) ,cos(theta/2)]])

Ry = UGate((0,), Ry_mat)
Rx= UGate((1,), Rx_mat)
c = Ry* Ry

print(qapply(c*Qubit('00'))) # -sin(theta/2)**2*|00> + 2*sin(theta/2)*cos(theta/2)*|01> + cos(theta/2)**2*|00>
```

I've filed an [issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/18733) for your problem. In the meantime, use `ImmutableMatrix`.