# Symbolic library for qubit states

Tags: programming, quantum-state

Is there any symbolic package (in Python or Julia, for example) that can represent qubit state coefficients symbolically?

For example, let's assume we have an initial two-qubit state:

$$ | \psi \rangle
= c_1 |01\rangle + c_2 |11\rangle + c_3 |00\rangle.
$$

Maybe I want to act with $R_Y (\theta)$ on the first qubit and then act with a Hadamard on the second qubit and so on.

Can I still get the final state in terms of symbols $c_1, c_2, c_3, \theta$, etc?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe mathematica?

Comment: related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/16960/55

Answer (score 1):

use [Wolfram quantum framework](http://wolfr.am/wolfram-quantum), that is the only framework supporting symbolic quantum computations, as far as I know
[image]